# Accessing a variable globally (Java)

Tags: java, android, static, enums, singleton

I'm developing an application for Android, and at one point the user chooses a region, after which the contents of all parts of the app is changed. Therefore I need to access an integer throughout the program. I have considered a singleton class, but I can't figure out how to add just an int, a get() and a set() to it (I want to be able to read everywhere and write in two classes(everywhere is fine)).

Should I simply declare it global?

This is what I've got going now, is it ok?

```
public enum Region {
INSTANCE;
private int rID =0;

public void setRID(int rID) {
    this.rID=rID;

}

public int getRID()
{
    return rID;
}

}
```

To be accessed with

```
Region.INSTANCE.setRID(5);
```

Comment: You have two choices: A) Singleton. You can find numerous examples here on SO and on the net. This is best accomplished in Java using an `Enum`. B) Dependency injection. This is preferred. You should simply be passing this information to your objects' constructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with an enum:

```
public enum Region {
INSTANCE;
private int rID =0;

    public void setRID(int rID)
    {
        this.rID=rID;

    }

    public int getRID()
    {
        return rID;
    }
}
```

Which I access with

```
Region.INSTANCE.getRID();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Singleton, but a static class. A class that contains a static field (a field not bounded to an instance):

```
public class StaticClass {

    private static int value;

    private Singleton () {}

    public static int getValue () {
       return value;
    }
    public static void setValue (int val) {
       value = val;
    }

}
```

you can access the value by `StaticClass.getValue()` and set the value by `StaticClass.getValue(4)`. ('StaticClass must not be replaced by an object).

The private constructor prevents one to create an instance by accident.

Comment: It's a global variable. I don't see why this could not be a solution to the problem of the OP.

Comment: Better, still not threadsafe. Singletons in java are best implemented using an `Enum`.

Comment: This isn't a singleton.  Static variables are harder to change later if something about how they are managed needs to vary.  See: http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: Why not declare the class static? It's not like the user will make instances of a class like this.

Comment: I know the singleton pattern. I don't see why it would be usefull. Mostly global variables are set in fixed adress space where instance variables are on the heap. This will introduce overhead. Furthermore Singletons are sometimes commented as bad practice. @Brian Roach I don't see the problem with threadsafety as its only an integer that will be set, there is not inconsistent state.

Comment: However a better solution to the entire problem would be to use an Observer pattern. If the users interacts with the system, a list of objects that need to be modified will be notified through a general interface.

Comment: Without using `volatile` with your primitive you risk a thread having a cached copy and not seeing a change.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
public class State
{
     static State instance = new State ();
     public static State getInstance() { return instance; }

     private int value;
     public void setValue (int value) { this.value = value; }
     public int getValue () { return value; }
}
```

Don't forget to store your value when your application exits, and restore it when it reloads.

Comment: I suppose that's another question, but is there a possibility to run a method when the application is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static class and declare the setter and getter as public.